# How to automatically export oracle environment variable required to run a ruby script?

Tags: ruby, oracle

My ruby script requires connection to an Oracle database. So I need to export ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH correctly before the script would run. Is there a way that I can export those env variables without using shell script? I tried to put ENV['ORACLE_HOME'] = '/usr/local/oracle_client' at the first line of the script and it doesn't work.
Now the only way it would work is to write a shell script, where export those variables and then run ruby there. The shell script looks like:

export ORACLE_HOME='/usr/local/oracle_client'
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/local/oracle_client/lib'
ruby myscript.rb --options

It's kinda ugly because user has to go inside the shell script to change options. I'm wondering whether there's a better way of doing it. So user can just do at command line: ruby myscript.rb --options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not supply the ruby options as arguments to the shell script? E.g.,

```
#!/bin/bash    
export ORACLE_HOME='/usr/local/oracle_client' 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/local/oracle_client/lib' 
ruby myscript.rb $*
```

Obviously you may want to add argument reasonableness checks, etc., but this gives the idea.

Comment: Cause he is not the consumer of his script, so it's better to save the clinets such conf...

Comment: What client configuration do you mean? OP said the script was ugly because the user has to modify script to supply options. This answer addresses that concern. It gives a command line solution no more complex than running the ruby command. It also adds value, as default options and validation can be done in the shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Why not call it out via `Kernel.system`?

```
system("export ORACLE_HOME='/usr/local/oracle_client'")
system("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/local/oracle_client/lib'")
```

Comment: You mean I put those lines at top of the script? I tried, but when I printed the env variable (puts ENV['ORACLE_HOME']), they're still empty.

Comment: It doesn't work because, as the documentation for the kernel.system says: "Executes cmd in a subshell, ...". As soon as the system call completes, the subshell exits (hence it's environment is gone), and you're back to square one.

Comment: What you really need is something akin to Perl's Env module, but I know zip about ruby so I can't say if there's anything available along those lines...